# how to remove duplicate from result in datastax solr

Tags: solr, datastax

```
wt=json&indent=true&q=*%3A*&start=0&rows=100&fq=scorer%3A2269ae85-b738-49c2-b188-17c3d79400a6
```

I am Getting Response Like :

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "response":{"numFound":5,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        **"tournament_scheduler_id":"e405cfab-18c6-43df-ab6d-1279b91cddaa",**
        "modified_date":"2016-01-08T14:20:48.433Z",
        "win_team_runs":0,
        "elect_to":"Elected to bat",
        "ground_id":"93b5d90c-16a9-4fb8-a21f-f549bb080ac5",
        "scorer":["2269ae85-b738-49c2-b188-17c3d79400a6"],
        "modified_by":"96588171-ef8b-43f2-a86d-e7d3460aac29",
        "tournament_id":"1ff0ae4e-146e-4ef1-ad07-507d0b9be9de",
        "no_of_overs":20,
        "lose_team_wickets":0,
        "created_by":"96588171-ef8b-43f2-a86d-e7d3460aac29",
        "created_date":"2016-01-07T07:01:24.419Z",
        "away_team_id":"e3ca398f-ae3b-42f0-bc87-e0edadaebb53",
        "lose_team_runs":0,
        "match_type":"Twenty 20",
        "status":"InProgress",
        "game_date":"2016-01-30T00:00:00Z",
        "win_team_wickets":0,
        "status_of_match":"",
        "toss_won_by":"e38877ec-f44f-498f-ada1-049d097a13dc",
        "home_team_id":"e38877ec-f44f-498f-ada1-049d097a13dc",
        "active":1,
        "umpire_id_1":"679c0940-b1da-4297-a969-4d0be8018b1b",
        "umpire_id_2":"ae28b91d-58af-4f00-92f9-4f7f3ce61ec5"},
      {
        "tournament_scheduler_id":"cca34732-d2d0-4662-9567-2748d9b3888d",
        "modified_date":"2016-01-07T10:56:23.385Z",
        "win_team_runs":0,
        "elect_to":"Elected to bat",
        "ground_id":"485cdf29-bf9b-4330-aa31-e2e3a411c741",
        "scorer":["2269ae85-b738-49c2-b188-17c3d79400a6"],
        "modified_by":"63b4a76f-b9c3-49da-8f31-6772ac5d3dc5",
        "tournament_id":"c91244a0-a42a-44a3-bf10-a20023d4d2e9",
        "no_of_overs":20,
        "lose_team_wickets":0,
        "created_by":"63b4a76f-b9c3-49da-8f31-6772ac5d3dc5",
        "created_date":"2016-01-06T06:26:04.765Z",
        "away_team_id":"a0dad51e-1398-413f-9d4d-cdff470e90c2",
        "lose_team_runs":0,
        "match_type":"Twenty 20",
        "status":"InProgress",
        "game_date":"2016-01-15T00:00:00Z",
        "win_team_wickets":0,
        "status_of_match":"",
        "toss_won_by":"a0dad51e-1398-413f-9d4d-cdff470e90c2",
        "home_team_id":"f62b86f9-2b65-4352-964b-9572803835d9",
        "active":1,
        "umpire_id_1":"acb01386-5fc6-45db-a186-715ec2fd7ce2"},
      {
        **"tournament_scheduler_id":"e405cfab-18c6-43df-ab6d-1279b91cddaa",**
        "modified_date":"2016-01-08T14:20:48.433Z",
        "win_team_runs":0,
        "elect_to":"Elected to bat",
        "ground_id":"93b5d90c-16a9-4fb8-a21f-f549bb080ac5",
        "scorer":["2269ae85-b738-49c2-b188-17c3d79400a6"],
        "modified_by":"96588171-ef8b-43f2-a86d-e7d3460aac29",
        "tournament_id":"1ff0ae4e-146e-4ef1-ad07-507d0b9be9de",
        "no_of_overs":20,
        "lose_team_wickets":0,
        "created_by":"96588171-ef8b-43f2-a86d-e7d3460aac29",
        "created_date":"2016-01-07T07:01:24.419Z",
        "away_team_id":"e3ca398f-ae3b-42f0-bc87-e0edadaebb53",
        "lose_team_runs":0,
        "match_type":"Twenty 20",
        "status":"InProgress",
        "game_date":"2016-01-30T00:00:00Z",
        "win_team_wickets":0,
        "status_of_match":"",
        "toss_won_by":"e38877ec-f44f-498f-ada1-049d097a13dc",
        "home_team_id":"e38877ec-f44f-498f-ada1-049d097a13dc",
        "active":1,
        "umpire_id_1":"679c0940-b1da-4297-a969-4d0be8018b1b",
        "umpire_id_2":"ae28b91d-58af-4f00-92f9-4f7f3ce61ec5"},
      {
        "tournament_scheduler_id":"c012b682-b0d9-4f75-8261-a6f4728f70a0",
        "modified_date":"2016-01-08T17:17:51.043Z",
        "win_team_runs":0,
        "elect_to":"",
        "ground_id":"93b5d90c-16a9-4fb8-a21f-f549bb080ac5",
        "scorer":["2269ae85-b738-49c2-b188-17c3d79400a6"],
        "modified_by":"96588171-ef8b-43f2-a86d-e7d3460aac29",
        "tournament_id":"1ff0ae4e-146e-4ef1-ad07-507d0b9be9de",
        "no_of_overs":0,
        "lose_team_wickets":0,
        "created_by":"96588171-ef8b-43f2-a86d-e7d3460aac29",
        "created_date":"2016-01-08T17:17:51.043Z",
        "away_team_id":"e3ca398f-ae3b-42f0-bc87-e0edadaebb53",
        "lose_team_runs":0,
        "match_type":"",
        "status":"Upcoming",
        "game_date":"2016-02-24T00:00:00Z",
        "win_team_wickets":0,
        "status_of_match":"",
        "home_team_id":"e38877ec-f44f-498f-ada1-049d097a13dc",
        "active":1,
        "umpire_id_1":"679c0940-b1da-4297-a969-4d0be8018b1b"},
      {
        "tournament_scheduler_id":"93be7a28-4867-461a-bff2-d81615c6d360",
        "modified_date":"2016-01-08T18:59:47.567Z",
        "win_team_runs":0,
        "elect_to":"Elected to bowl",
        "ground_id":"485cdf29-bf9b-4330-aa31-e2e3a411c741",
        "scorer":["2269ae85-b738-49c2-b188-17c3d79400a6"],
        "modified_by":"63b4a76f-b9c3-49da-8f31-6772ac5d3dc5",
        "tournament_id":"c91244a0-a42a-44a3-bf10-a20023d4d2e9",
        "no_of_overs":20,
        "lose_team_wickets":0,
        "created_by":"63b4a76f-b9c3-49da-8f31-6772ac5d3dc5",
        "created_date":"2016-01-08T14:31:35.298Z",
        "away_team_id":"f62b86f9-2b65-4352-964b-9572803835d9",
        "lose_team_runs":0,
        "match_type":"Twenty 20",
        "status":"InProgress",
        "game_date":"2016-03-14T00:00:00Z",
        "win_team_wickets":0,
        "status_of_match":"",
        "toss_won_by":"f62b86f9-2b65-4352-964b-9572803835d9",
        "home_team_id":"a0dad51e-1398-413f-9d4d-cdff470e90c2",
        "active":1,
        "umpire_id_1":"4e113da2-5be9-40e5-a689-1a3e9d959c3d"}]
  }}
```

here,**tournament_scheduler_id** is uniquekey in core

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: how to remove duplicates from result in above result  **"tournament_scheduler_id":"e405cfab-18c6-43df-ab6d-1279b91cddaa",** is repeating in solr core tournament_scheduler_id is unique

Comment: Whats your C* create table statement